# Azure Function v1 as SOAP endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, soap, azure-functions

I have an azure function app (v1, with no possibility for upgrading, unfortunately) with an endpoint receiving JSON via POST requests, doing some computation and returning JSON in the response. This endpoint needs to be made SOAP-compatible, meaning that it should receive SOAP requests and return SOAP responses and also be able to provide a WSDL file.

Using the SOAP mapper in API Management is not an option, due to its limitations.

The methods I have tried are:

1. Create a WCF service and try to delegate the HTTP request to it from the Azure function endpoint. This didn't seem to work because the corresponding handler in WCF can only receive a request via its own HTTP endpoint (which does not seem to be exposable via the azure function endpoint), but cannot be called from within the code.
2. Use an ASP.net web application with [SoapCore](https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCore) as a starting point and try to migrate it to an azure function. This doesn't seem possible because of a completely different structure. SoapCore is attached to the ASP.net app instance as a middleware, whereas azure function does not provide the means to use middleware.
3. Parse the SOAP request manually, convert it to JSON, do the computation, convert the result back to a SOAP message and return it. The seems very hacky and also the WSDL must be created and served manually. Despite these drawbacks, I'm leaning towards this solution because of the unfeasibility of the first two.

Is there any other possible solution that I have might missed?

Comment: How did you solve your issue in the end? Any update? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure API Management , then below option works;

You can write transformation policies at the service or endpoint level - JSON to SOAP refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#convert-json-to-soap-using-a-liquid-template

Also refer this link [Expose REST API as SOAP via Azure API Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52769635/expose-rest-api-as-soap-via-azure-api-management) would help.

Comment: We cannot use APIM SOAP Converter, because of its limitations. Forgot to add that in the original question, sorry.